# how to make laravel 9 api-only?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-9

Is there a way to make laravel api-only?(for optimized speed)
I wanted to use lumen but it's not listed in the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/) anymore. Is there anyway to achive this?

Comment: just don't return any view

Comment: [Lumen 9](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x) exists. What do you mean by it's not listed in the docs anymore?

Comment: What do you mean with make laravel api-only? Just use API routes and don't use views. Be aware that not all functionalities are available in Lumen. IE: form requests are not supported, If you would like to use form requests, you should use the full Laravel framework. IMO, go for laravel, there is almost no performance difference

Comment: @D1__1 oh I think they just recently added lumen 9. I checked a couple days ago and the last version was lumen 8. about your question; in the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com) there is no name of lumen in the ecosystems or packages section.

Comment: @Luciano can you clartify on how "there is almost no performance difference"? They claim lumen can handle up to 1900 req/s.

Comment: @D1__1 Lumen doesn't support Laravel octane which can boost laravel performance

Comment: "[...] we no longer recommend that you begin new projects with Lumen. Instead, we recommend always beginning new projects with Laravel." - https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as indicated by @D1__1, there exist Lumen 9.
If you still considers the option of using laravel 9, then I will suggest doing the following:

1. Using the api routes only
2. Implementing JWT https://laravel-jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/laravel-installation/
3. [Optional] Change the exception handler to output errors as not expose details of your applications.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was looking for a JWT that works with Laravel 9.

Comment: One important thing: lumen page says it'll only receive bug fixes e no more development. I'd go with Laravel. Maybe slimphp + eloquent

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer. I did this recently by only using the API routes and securing them with the Auth0 sdk. My frontend is in Vue and the SPA retrieves access tokens from Auth0, then calls my Laravel API and passes the token on each request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).